# draw a transparent flat surface using mplot3d in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to show a separation between my 3d plot data. Like dividing them between top and bottom of `Z = 100` surface.

This is my code:

```py
# x, y, t are lists of points that shows (x,y) coordinate of an object at time t

cor_x = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(t, x, 5))
cor_y = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(t, y, 5))

ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot3D(cor_x(t), cor_y(t), t)
plt.show()
```

All I want is a transparent z = 100 surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot a surface use `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)`. Where X,Y are the 2d grid created with `np.meshgrid` and Z is the data on the same grid. You can make the z=100 surface by taking your data and multiplying by zero and adding 100.

You can use `alpha` to change the transparency. Note that the more transparent the harder to see which may not be the best approach to separate your data.

Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, y):
    return x**2 + y**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


x = y = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, .1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = f(X,Y)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,color='gray',alpha=.8)


#To plot the surface at 100, use your same grid but make all your numbers zero
Z2 = Z*0.+100
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z2,color='r',alpha=.3) #plot the surface

plt.show()
```

[image]